# How to hide custom button in product details page by particular category in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-detail-page

How to hide custom button  in product details  page  by particular category in magento 2

In magento 2, custom button will be hidden for each product from the selected categories in admin.  I want to  admin setting is applied to  product details page in frontend.

**Admin Setting**

[image: product]

**Frontend**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

==>You can get the current product category using the below code.

**NOTE: Please do not use the Object manager**

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View')->getProduct();
$categoryId = $product->getCategoryId();
echo $categoryId;

?>
```

==>And now get the array of the selected category from your backend and write the login as per the below code.

```
<?php
$selectedCategory = [2,3,5];

if (!in_array($categoryId , $selectedCategory))
    # code...
    #Add To Quote
}
?>
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**

Comment: it reflects a \view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml:47:boolean false

Comment: it not show a category  id

Comment: Please check your class method in template. If there class method is available wich I was used in my code than work according.

Comment: Other way you can assigned the the template with block wich i used in above code.